# How do I resolve the error message: Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer

Tags: windows-10, pagefile

I booted my machine, and suddenly got this pop-up:

> Windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a
>   problem that occurred with your paging file configuration when you
>   started your computer.  The total paging file size for all disk drives
>   may be somewhat larger than the size you specified.

When I close the pop-up, I see the Performance dialog saying `Total paging file size for all drives: 0 MB`. I've never changed pagefile settings, and the <kbd>Change...</kbd> button shows that it's set to `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives`.

I've tried to set to the different settings belowand reboot, but always got the same popup:

1. Select drive, set to system manage size
2. Select drive, set to `No paging file`
3. `Custom size:` Initial: 5000MB, Maximum: 10000MB

[This answers.microsoft.com post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/message-at-startup-windows-created-a-temporary/9f041f2f-2e59-4dbe-8da9-71cee2881367) suggests I:

- Disable pagefile - Even if I do, I get the same pop-up
- Delete c:\pagefile.sys - can't get deleted
- Set partition pagefile attribute using `DISKPART` - but `HELP ATTRIBUTES DISK` says `READONLY is currently the only disk flag that may be changed`.

### Specs

- Machine: Lenovo X230, 16GB RAM
- Disk: Samsung Evo 850, formatted as a single C: drive.
- OS: Windows 10 (version 1511) 64-bit

Comment: How much free space on `C:` ?

Comment: 60GB - should suffice

Comment: Turn off page file and reboot, then re enable it, see if this solves the error message.

Comment: Did that, doesn't fix the issue. I also upgraded to Windows Insider Preview build 14251 - same issue.